# TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Tags: python, eval

I'm trying to evaluate a function at x0

```
f = lambda x:mu*div2d(grad2d(x))+x-b
```

I tried this:

```
def feval(f, *args):
    return eval(f)(*args)
feval(f,x0)
```

but it throws up a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-128-6be96feb06d6>", line 1, in <module>
    feval(f,x0)

  File "<ipython-input-126-67b053764219>", line 2, in feval
    return eval(f)(*args)

TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

I also read that using eval() is bad practice. What'd be a good way to do this then? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to call a function, just call it: `return f(*args)`.

Comment: In fact, you've just reproduced a less powerful version of the ancient [`apply`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply) function, which was deprecated in Python 2.3 and removed in 3.0 because it really isn't useful. Instead of `feval(f, x0)` you can just call `f(x0)`.

Comment: `eval` is only used to convert strings into python expressions. E.g., `eval('f(*args)')` is same as `f(*args)`, but using the former makes no sense in this case.

Comment: Never thought I'd have to search for a duplicate for the question "How do I call a function?"...

Comment: @Aran-Fey I couldn't find one. There are a few questions about `apply` which are relevant, but I think explaining why they're relevant to the OP would take as much writing as answering directly. Hopefully you can find something better?

Comment: @abarnert Afraid not. The most relevant answer I found is the one down v there v :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function evaluates a string as if it were source code.<sup>1</sup> For example, `eval("f(*args)")` would do the same thing as calling `f(*args)` directly.

But you don't have source code, you have a function. To call a function, all you have to do is:

```
return f(*args)
```

It doesn't matter that you got the function as a parameter, `f`, instead of directly from a `def` statement or `lambda` expression. Function values are just objects, like anything else in Python, and you can pass them around the same as any other values, and then call them whenever you want.

---

But really, there's no need for this function at all. Instead of this:

```
feval(f, x0)
```

… you could just call it directly:

```
f(x0)
```

The only reason you'd ever need something like your `feval` is if someone else has passed you a function and a bunch of arguments separately, and you need to put them together into a function call. Python used to have a function for this, [`apply`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply), but it was removed long ago because it's almost never necessary, and a one-liner if it ever is necessary.

---

> I also read that using eval() is bad practice.

It usually is. That's because it's about treating strings as code:

- If the string comes out of your source code, you probably didn't need `eval` and could just run the code. That's why you don't want to use it here.
- If, on the other hand, the string comes from user input or the internet or something, it can be dangerous—something like `"__import__('os').system('mr -rf /')"` is just one typo away from being a really bad idea to evaluate.

---

<sub>1. It can also evaluate compiled code objects, which is why the error message is a bit more complicated than you might expect, but don't worry about that.</sub>